# ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY) gives same row numbers

Tags: sql, hana

I use SAP HANA database for a project. I tried this SQL query to get values with a row number. But it gives 1 as all rows.

```
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "ItemCode") AS "ID", "ItemCode", "CommitedQty", "JobId", "WarehouseID"
    FROM
        (SELECT "ItemCode", SUM("CommitedQty") AS "CommitedQty","JobId", "WarehouseID"
        FROM "Stock" 
        WHERE "BaseEntry" = 10352
        GROUP BY "ItemCode","JobId", "WarehouseID")
```

This is the result that I get.

[image]

Why all row numbers are became 1. How do I solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: You do only have 1 in each item code, you need row_number without partition, but order by i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this : `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY code)` it is continue sequence and you use `partition by` it manse it reset every code.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "ItemCode") AS "ID", "ItemCode", "CommitedQty", "JobId", "WarehouseID"
    FROM
        (SELECT "ItemCode", SUM("CommitedQty") AS "CommitedQty","JobId", "WarehouseID"
        FROM "Stock" 
        WHERE "BaseEntry" = 10352
        GROUP BY "ItemCode","JobId", "WarehouseID")
```

Comment: Even if the answer is correct, it would be great if you write a short explanation of what was wrong and why your solution gives the correct result.

Comment: @D.Mika i explain what is problem there.